# Accessing returned data by method in spring cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, ehcache

I've a `Person` which has `id` and `name`.

When I search by `Id` the method returned the `Person` Object and I want to make `name` as cache key but the returned data is not accessible in `key` tag of `Cacheable` annotation but the `name` is accessible in `unless` tag.

```
@Cacheable(value = "Cache", key = "#result.name", unless="#result.name == 'Foo'")
public Person getById(String id){}
```

If I use `key = "#result.name"` it gives me exception :

> EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null

What am I missing, How can I access returned data from method in `key` tag?

Comment: The cache key is based on the parameter(s) of the method (not the content of the return type).  Why do you want to cache by name when the search is by id?

Comment: So, there is no way to access the returned data in `key` tag like we do in `unless`? I mean If it's accessible in `unless` why it's not accessible in `key` tag?

Comment: The method takes an id, but assume somehow the cache key was based on the name attribute.  Next time the method is called, how would an entry in the the cache be located?  **After** the cache lookup is complete (or the real method is invoked), `unless` can filter the returned value.

Comment: can you share your method signature to which you are applying caching

Comment: @Yogi I've updated the question.

Comment: @ItiGupta See my response as Answer with explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your use case this is not possible since the cache key gets generated from the parameter you're passing to the method and that's `String id`. Therefore Spring tries to extract the `name` parameter from the String. Which is not possible.

Even if it was possible to use the name of the result as cache key the cache wouldn't work as you're querying by `id`.

Comment: Is there NO WAY to access result in `key`?

Comment: @ItiGupta you're using the key to load the result. So there's no chance that you can access the result before having loading it.

Comment: Ohh, now it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: With Cacheable the use case makes no sense, but with CachePut the basic use case of "create and return entity", where EntityManager creates the identifier for a new entity and returns the updated entity, it would make sense as the returned entity should be cached (unless I have completely misunderstood the framework).

Answer (score 0):

Cache keys should generated from method parameter on which you are applying caching and you cache result of method.

Working code will be:

```
@Cacheable(value = "personCache", key = "#id", unless="#person.name == 'Foo'")
public Person getById(String id){

    Person person = data initialization logic here;
    return person;
}
```

For more information on Caching go through [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) link.

For some best practice follow [this](https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks) blog.

Comment: `Cache keys should generated from method parameter` that's the problem, I've to choose the `key` from response(if possible). I'm not sure why it's not accessible in 'key` area but accessible in `unless`.

Comment: Because unless works on result of method and key works on input, key decides whether to use cache or not before calling actual implementation. unless is condition for whether to store result in cache or not. Reading this docs...https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache